# New row count after each TH

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a few rows with  and a few ones with  following. Is there a way to apply style to the TDs as in odd/even restarting after every row with THs with jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>header 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>445</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7899</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>asd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ddd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ggg</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can use css classes, or there exist jquery widgets for zebra striping.

Comment: In addition to plugins, you can check out the [n-th child selector](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

Comment: That's true, I can add class to tr:nth-child(even) but I would like to count each first row after header as odd...

Comment: Why not just make two tables?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo I used two segments in example, but the real table is longer.

Answer (score 4):

```
var i = 0;

$('table tr').each(function() {

    if ($(this).is(':has(th)')) return i = 0;    
    $(this).children().addClass(i++ % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u9hjA/

Comment: +1 Why not add the class to the `tr` and reduce code: `$(this).addClass(i++ % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');`

Comment: Nice. Nice. Nice. Just add the class to the `tr` and not the `td`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to exclude any nested tables withing the main one?

Comment: Depends on your css, etc but `.children('td')` or remove it all together.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tvyfz/2/

```
$(function () {
   var zc = 0;

   $('table tr').each (function (idx, el) {
      if ($(el).find('th').length != 0) {
         zc = 0;
      } else {
         $(el).addClass((++zc%2)?'even':'odd');
      }

   });
});
```

**Note:** Your markup didn't had a proper closing `</tr>`

**Edit:** minor cleanup.

Comment: Note that this adds the class to the `tr` not the `td` like OP asks. Just needs a `.children()`

Comment: @stevether I wouldn't add zebra styling to Td's.